# Access Ubuntu terminal in Window 10 in dual booting system

Tags: dual-boot

I use dual booting system (Ubuntu 16.04, Window 10) in my laptop.

I want to access Ubuntu terminal in Windows.

Is it possible? If it is, then how to do that?

I've followed some instructions in google about remote control Ubuntu from Window but they don't work. I think the reason is I have to reboot in Ubuntu to change boot in Window.

Thanks.

Comment: Remote control of a Ubuntu machine from a Windows machine requires both machines to be running. What are you trying to achieve with a Ubuntu terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dual boot means, that you can boot one or the other system. Not both at a time.

So if you want to access an Ubuntu terminal from Windows, you need a second PC to run Ubuntu and then you can connect to it via an SSH client like Putty.(SSH must be set up/enabled on the Ubuntu machine.)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments above, but wanted to add that you can also run an Ubuntu VM from Windows using either VMWare Player or Oracle Virtualbox.  That would use extra system resources, but may accomplish what you are looking to do.